# ubuntu boot option lost after restoring bios settings

Tags: dual-boot, 16.04

I have a dell inspiron 15 that I bought about 7 months ago with windows 7 pre-installed. I added a dual boot for ubuntu 16.04 LTS and had been using it until 2 weeks ago, when my battery died. I was not sure if the battery was actually died so I searched for a solution online. One post I read said that it may have to do with bios settings. So I tried restoring bios settings in the boot menu under general (after pressing F2 when booting). Obviously it did not help with the battery since it was actually dead. But now when I boot I cannot see the ubuntu boot option anymore. I have spent quite some time configuring my Ubuntu and would like to get it back rather than reinstalling a new one and start fresh. How can I do it?

**EDIT:**
I have been tried to boot from different options to no avail. Here is a screen shot of what I have now (with USB ubuntu plugged in). [image]
As you can see, there are 3 boot options:

```
UEFI: Lexar USB Flash Drive 1100, Partition 1
UEFI: WDC WD10JPVX-75JC3TO, Partition 1
Windows Boot Manager
```

The 1st one (Lexar) is on the USB drive, which is a fresh download. I would think that the 2nd should be what I want, but it goes into windows too if I select it.

Comment: Check your boot options and make sure the first device is the drive where your OSes are installed.

Comment: @CelticWarrior I have changed the order of boot options quite a few times since this happened. They all go into windows so far.

Comment: make a live cd of ubuntu and try to boot that cd , keep going on until you prompt with window asking you to install ubuntu newly or along side existing one(which you lost and  is detected by live ubuntu automatically).

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get grub boot options back with the boot-repair tool mentioned [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair).

Answer (score 0):

Try to change boot mode from legacy to uefi or vice versa, and change the sequence to ubuntu first.
You can find this in the boot sequence settings in the bios menu.